# Serverless - Local path and Lambda Path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm wondering how I can force my local serverless deployment to mimic what happens when I deploy it to AWS.

Here is my serverless yaml file:

```
service: payment # NOTE: update this with your service name

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"
environment:
SLS_DEBUG: "*"

provider:
name: aws
runtime: nodejs8.10
stage: production
region: ca-central-1
timeout: 60
role: ${file(../config/prod.env.json):ROLE}
vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
    - ${file(../config/prod.env.json):SECURITY_GROUP}
    subnetIds:
    - ${file(../config/prod.env.json):SUBNET}
apiGateway:
    apiKeySourceType: HEADER
apiKeys:
    - ${file(../config/prod.env.json):APIKEY}

package:
include:
    - ../lib/**

functions:
- '${file(src/handlers/payment.serverless.yml)}'

plugins:
- serverless-offline
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
root
--- node_modules
--- lib
    - models
--- payment
    - serverless.yml
```

When I deploy it to AWS the lib folder gets put into the lambda function's folder but locally I need to define its path which usually is ../.../../

How can I make it so that locally or deployed I don't have to change the paths?

Answer (score 0):

There is a docker container that is extremely close to aws lambda. You can deploy your serverless onto the container and trial and error with what you want done.
You can also create a lambda layer, which serverless supports, this way.

Comment: the issue is how serverless deploys the code. when you run it locally, it doesn't execute it the same way as when you deploy.

Comment: Serverless, similar to terraform, tries to run all the dependencies in parallel that it can at deployment time. The only way to enforce an order for resource evaluation is to create a dependency between them. I would suggest creating that docker container and testing out your deployment there and creating dependencies between your resources so that a order is created. To my knowledge this is the only way due to how Serverless works.